# handling JSON response that is not the same each time

Tags: c#, json, exception

i am working with json.net to deserialize json -> C# objects.

it works great in most cases but there are times where rather than getting an array i get object.

so my class (generated using http://json2csharp.com/ and modified to add property).
where i more than 1 arrival methods (such as pick up or ship) it works fine.

```
public class ArrivalMethods
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ArrivalMethod")]
        public List<string> ArrivalMethod { get; set; }
    }
```

but it breaks where there only 1 arrival method in the json response from my service because i believe json.net is expecting an object like below.

```
public class ArrivalMethods
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ArrivalMethod")]
        public string ArrivalMethod { get; set; }
    }
```

i am new to json etc. so i am not sure what i am doing wrong. but this throws exception.

```
    Error converting value \"Ship\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'. 
Path 'ProductDetail.SoftHardProductDetails.Fulfillment.
ArrivalMethods.ArrivalMethod', line 1, position 113."
```

here is where it breaks:

```
"ArrivalMethods":{
"ArrivalMethod":"Ship"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON should contain [] where there is a list. And if I'm understanding your answer correct, the first class example is the way you want to end up? If so  you need the JSON on the bottom to mark ArrivalMethod as a list, wich its not now.

```
"ArrivalMethods":
{
"ArrivalMethod":["Ship"]
},
```

To be honest i get a little confused when there is a list with no plural ending.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the response format that would be the best. It really looks like XML semantics converted to JSON...

If you can't change the response format, you can try to use [JsonConverterAttribute](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) to create custom converters for those properties.